# Node.js password salting/hashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

In view of the recent LinkedIn breach, would anyone care to review my data access routines relating to user access?

This is a standard node.js module, accessing a Postgres database.

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var crypto = require('crypto'),
        hash = function (pass, salt) {
            var h = crypto.createHash('sha512');

            h.update(pass);
            h.update(salt);

            return h.digest('base64');
        };

    module.exports.getUser = function (conn, email, password, callback) {
        conn.query({
            name: 'getUser',
            text: 'SELECT "id", "passwordHash" FROM "user" WHERE "email" = $1 LIMIT 1',
            values: [email]
        }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            if (result.rows.length === 0) {
                callback(null);
            } else {
                var newHash = hash(password, email),
                    row = result.rows[0];

                if (row.passwordHash === newHash) {
                    callback({id: row.id, email: email});
                } else {
                    callback(null);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    module.exports.addUser = function (conn, email, password, callback) {
        var newHash = hash(password, email);

        conn.query({
            name: 'addUser',
            text: 'INSERT INTO "user" ("email", "passwordHash") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"',
            values: [email, newHash]
        }, function (err, result) {
            var id;

            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                callback(null);
            } else {
                id = result.rows[0].id;

                callback({id: id, email: email});
            }
        });
    };

}());
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me, but I wouldn't use the email as the hash salt because it doesn't provide enough entropy. I always use a GUID as a salt because it ensures that `bits(password+salt) > bits(hash())`

Comment: OK, so perhaps where I do `h.update(pass); h.update(salt);`, I should also add `h.update(<secret-guid>);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not see anything immediately wrong with your `addUser()` and `getUser()` implementations.
Your `hash()` implementation could be improved in two areas though.

1. **Salt**
   As already indicated by Bill Barry in the comments, your should use a better salt.
   Some rules to keep in mind when handling salts,

   - **Salts should be unique per password.**
      Every password should have a unique salt. Sharing a salt reduces its effectiveness.
   - **Salts should be unpredictable**
     You should generate a salt using a Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator ([CSPRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)).

     You may want to try using [crypto.randomBytes(size, [callback])](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) if available.
   - **Salts should be large**
      [PKCS#5](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127) recommends a salt be no smaller than 64-bits (8 bytes).
     I like to start with 128-bit salts (16 bytes), favoring higher salt-lengths for more passwords and better security.
   - **Salts are not secret**
     Although purposefully disclosing the salt isn't a good idea, you can store them in cleartext.
2. **Key stretching / Iterations**
   Wikipedia has a good description on [Key Stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching),

   > key stretching refers to techniques used to make a possibly weak key, typically a password or passphrase, more secure against a brute force attack by increasing the time it takes to test each possible key.

   The `crypto` module does not appear to offer key stretching natively for sha512.

   You should look into using [crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_callback) which uses HMAC-SHA1. You shouldn't use SHA1 on its own, but `pbkdf2` using HMAC-SHA1 is still secure.
   See [Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for more information.

   You will want to set the number of iterations as high as possible while still maintaining an acceptable responsiveness for your application. Though [PKCS#5](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127) recommends a minimum of 1000 iterations, 10000+ iterations is fairly typical; computers are only getting faster.

Answer (score 0):

@Jared Paolin's answer is good.

Expanding on it a little:

1. The salt should be exactly the same length as the hash.
2. When you verify, always use a constant-time algorithm so that attackers can't play hangman to guess passwords. If it takes longer to get a response for a mostly right password, attackers can use that data to progressively guess the password one letter at a time.
3. For 2014, you need at least 128,000 iterations to be safe with PDKDF2 / HMAC-SHA1. Make sure to pass the work load in as a parameter to PDKDF2, so you can change it as processors get faster. Double the iterations every 2 years.